# return distance objects in Django

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have a small function like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

def RailTest(mod_ewdim, mod_ewspacing, cols): 
    y = Distance(inch=mod_ewspacing)
    x = Distance(inch=mod_ewdim)
    z = Distance(inch=3)
    l = ( (x*cols)+(y*(cols-1)) )+z
    return l
```

However when I call the function and I do `type(l)` it is of type `float`. How can I ensure I return a distance object.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
return Distance(inch=l)
```

Comment: Actually, I think I had some error in my shell. Running this code again it works and outputs a `Distance` object. Would it still be advisable to explicitly cast `l` as a `Distance` object?

Comment: Yes, given dynamic/duck-typing in Python, it would be advisable to explicitly cast it to make your code more readable + more in-line with defensive programming principles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
return Distance(inch=l)
```